# Toggling a class to an element when clicked using 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have an element it has no ID, eg.

```
<div class='classA' v-on:click='addClassB(this)'></div>
```

When you click on it I want a class to be added, or removed if it exists already, it calls this function:

```
methods: {
    addClassB: function () {
        this.classList.toggle("classB");
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, I want to be able to toggle 'classB' on just that item, because I could have something like this:

```
<div class='classA' v-on:click='addClassB(this)'></div>
<div class='classA' v-on:click='addClassB(this)'></div>
<div class='classA' v-on:click='addClassB(this)'></div>
```

So when one is clicked, I don't want all of them to have classB added, just the one clicked.

I am also using Vue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just access the [event target from the method itself](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers):

```
methods: {
    addClassB: function (event) {
        event.target.classList.toggle("classB");
    }
}
```

So there's no longer any need to pass any arguments into the handler:

```
<div class='classA' v-on:click='addClassB'></div>
```

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    addClassB(event) {
      event.target.classList.toggle('classB');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}
#app div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.classA {
  background: red;
}
.classB {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="classA" v-on:click="addClassB"></div>
  <div class="classA" v-on:click="addClassB"></div>
  <div class="classA" v-on:click="addClassB"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this` use `event.target`. From Vue doc - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers:

```
greet: function (event) {
  // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
  alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
  // `event` is the native DOM event
  if (event) {
    alert(event.target.tagName)
  }
}
```

In your code:

```
methods: {
    addClassB: function (event) {
        event.target.classList.toggle("classB");
    }
}
```

and:

```
<div class='classA' v-on:click='addClassB'></div>
```